# Unmask data from matrix linux shell

Tags: shell, matrix, data-masking

i have 2 file.

analizeddata.txt:

```
A001->A002->A003->A004
A001->A005->A007
A022->A033
[...]
```

and

matrix.txt:

```
A001|Scott
A002|Bob
A003|Mark
A004|Jane
A005|Elion
A007|Brooke
A022|Meggie
A023|Tif
[..]
```

How i can replace in analizeddata.txt, or obtain a new file, with the second column of matrix.txt?
The expected output file will be as:

```
Scott->Bob->Mark->Jane
Scott->Elion->Brooke
Meggie->Tif
[...]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `sed` to replace the string what you want.

- `sed 's/|/\//g' matrix.txt` will generate the replace pattern likes `A001/Scott` which will be used as `regexp/replacement` of the second `sed s/regexp/replacement/` command.
- `sed -i` option will update directly **analizeddata.txt** file, back up it before exec this command.

```
for replace_mode in $(sed 's/|/\//g' matrix.txt); do sed -i 's/'$replace_mode'/g' analizeddata.txt; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting `awk` script:

```
 awk -F"|" 'FNR==NR{arr[$1]=$2;next}{for(i in arr)gsub(i,arr[i])}1' matrix.txt analizeddata.txt
```

with provided sample data, results:

```
Scott->Bob->Mark->Jane
Scott->Elion->Brooke
Meggie->A033
```